# using controller functions to display multiple pages

Tags: cakephp

Lets say i have multiple public functions in a single controller, i am trying to fine a way to display 1 option per page for example, first page user selects a schoolYear then hit submit, next page the user selects a school and hit submit, 3rd page the user selects a term and with a final page of all the selected fields being shown and a delete button. i am starting to test my page now and am wondering what is the best way to accomplish this?

```
class SchoolYearsController extends AppController
{
public function index()
{

}

public function chooseYear()
{
    $schoolYearsTable = $this->loadModel('SchoolYears');

    $schoolYears = $schoolYearsTable->find()->order(['SchoolYears.endYear'=>'desc']);

    $this->set('schoolYears',$schoolYears);

    $this->request->getSession()->write('App.schoolYear',$this->request->getData('schoolYear'));

    return $this->redirect(['controller'=>'SchoolYears', 'action'=>'chooseSchool']);
}

public function chooseSchool()
{
    $schoolListsTable = $this->loadModel('Schools');

    $schoolYear = $this->session->read('App.schoolYear');
    $schools = $schoolListsTable->find()
    ->where([
        'fiscalYear' => $schoolYear,
        'districtCode' => 'MA',
    ])
    ;

    $this->set('schools',$schools);

    return $this->redirect(['controller'=>'SchoolYears', 'action'=>'chooseTerm']);
}

public function chooseTerm()
{
    $chosenTerm = $this->request->getData();
}
}
```

Comment: Lots of ways to do this. Session is one, as you've started. Or have each page render the next form (with all data received so far in hidden fields) when it gets valid data posted to it. Or redirect to the next page, with data received so far in the URL. Or an Ajax-based solution where you add fields or options as selections are made. Probably others that I'm not thinking of. Which is best is highly subjective, depending on your needs.

Comment: Any reason not to just have One Function and One View for Each Page? I'm trying to understand your question. Are you trying to have each page be the same, almost identical, but for the parts unique to which Step the user is on? You could do that with the "$this->render" command to choose the Same One View file for each Step, which can test for what step it's on based on what variables are passed, or the value of a Step Counter variable.